# Is it possible to color the output of `aafire`?

Tags: terminal, colors, output, ascii-art

The program seems cool, but giving it a red color really makes it look like my computer is on fire. I think using grep or similar piping command can do the trick, but I see that it prints ASCII escape codes for colors and removes the special formatting of the output that makes it look like fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `cacafire`

ASCII fire (`aafire`) was created with the now dead `libaa`. That may actually predate terminal color codes (I don't remember). However, the newer varient is the still maintained [`libcaca`](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) which provides `cacafire`.

[image: Cacafire]

Comment: On ubuntu the package is availble in "caca-utils"

Answer (score 0):

Using command line flags, you can configure the output to display in your terminal rather than a popup window.

```
aafire -driver stdout -width 80 # match width of your terminal
aafire --help # see available options
```

Now, the color is controlled using your shell application's preferences. For example, I am using gnome-terminal on Ubuntu, so I just go to the menu Edit>Profile Preferences.

As far as changing the font color and background color itself, this appears to be possible in principle:

```
aatest
```

Notice that the first line has a blue background. I imagine this is accomplished with escape characters specifying the background color. You can find lots of discussion about this with people asking about [changing their bash prompt color](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16120/in-bash-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-command-prompt).

In order to insert your escape characters to change the color, I am not sure it would be possible to do this from the shell. Perhaps you could write a custom bash script that accepts input from stdin, pipe the output of aafire into your script, echo the color-changing characters, and finally echo the message from stdin.

Alternatively, you might have to call the library, for instance from a C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <aalib.h>
aa_context *context;
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(!aa_parseoptions(NULL, NULL, &argc, argv) || argc!=1) {
    printf("Usage: %s [options]\n"
           "Options:\n"
           "%s", argv[0], aa_help);
    exit(1);
  }
  context = aa_autoinit(&aa_defparams);
  if(context == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot initialize AA-lib. Sorry\n");
    exit(2);
  }
  ...
  aa_close(context);
}
```

Example source code from the [aalib documentation](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/aalib_9.html).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
aafire -driver curses
```