# Run command on startup for one user

Tags: bash, shell, debian, login

I made a new user on my server. The user is not logged into the bash shell on startup. To do this I can run `/bin/bash --login` and it works.

Where do I place this command so that it runs automatically? I tried `~/.bashlogin'`, `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`. When I go back to login I see the user logging in, but the shell does looks like a shell without login. E.g.,

> user@computer:~/path$
> $
> $
> $

instead of

> user@computer:~/path
> user@computer:~/path
> user@computer:~/path

How to run the command `/bin/bash --login` without doing it yourself?

Comment: Bonus question: how do I add colors to this `user@computer:~/path` thing?

Comment: what is the output of `echo $0` when you login

Comment: I see `-sh` after running `echo $0` for the new user. After `/bin/bash --login` the result is `/bin/bash`. For root it is `-bash`

Comment: "a shell without login" That's just the prompt, not "the shell", and you can make it look any way you want. You are logged into the shell, but that shell is sh not bash. You want to [change the user 's shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22729/where-do-i-change-my-shell).

Comment: @user2609980 http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12335/33055 for coloring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you created a new user, but when logging in with that user, you get some other shell, but not `bash`. If this is your problem, then the solution is to change the shell of that new user to `/bin/bash`. This can be achieved with

> usermod -s /bin/bash *user*

Comment: You probably want to put `sudo ` before that.

Comment: Yeah, of course, unless already running as root.

Comment: Ah that is cleaner than my solution below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can run the `/bin/bash --login` command when I place it as the *first line* of the `~/.profile` file. I had another line that set the path variable (i.e., `PATH = "blablablabla"; export PATH`) and somehow that conflicted.

Now I am logged into the shell with the new user. Thanks for the help.

Only question that remains is how to give it pretty colours.