# Terminal command customization

Tags: bash, prompt

When I open my URxvt I can see this:

```
[username@Lenovo ~]$ ...
```

however, I can see someone can edit it to make it look like:

```
username ~ $ ...
```

with `username` formatted with a color. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please search for answers before posting a question, this has been asked many times before. e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/how-to-customize-bashrc-to-configure-command-prompt

Comment: It can indeed be done, as you know and saw.  You can use ANSI codes for the color.  PS1 is the variable used for the default prompt.

Comment: @icarus can you link me something?

Comment: See this previous question [How to customize .bashrc to configure command prompt?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/how-to-customize-bashrc-to-configure-command-prompt) or refer to the [ArchLinux wiki on Bash/Prompt customization](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is customizing your bash prompt. Here is a generator with instructions:
http://ezprompt.net